# how to send twilio sms using node https request

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to send an sms without the twilio sdk by using the nodejs https module however the twilio post api keeps responding with this error "400, Bad Request", which means I'm probably not crafting the request the right way. I've followed the nodejs docs https example, and also twilio's. I've also tried making curl post request and it works perfectly fine. Where I'm I getting it wrong. Here's my code

```
// Send an SMS message via Twilio
helpers.sendTwilioSms = (phone, message, callback) => {
  // validate parameters
  phone =
    typeof phone == "string" && phone.trim().length == 10
      ? phone.trim().length
      : false;
  message =
    typeof message == "string" &&
    message.trim().length > 0 &&
    message.trim().length <= 1600
      ? message.trim()
      : false;

  if (phone && message) {
    // Configure the request payload
    const payload = {
      from: config.twilio.fromPhone,
      to: `+234${phone}`,
      body: message
    };

// stringify payload using querystring module instead of JSON.stringify because the reqeust we'll be sending is not of application/json but 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' form content-type as specified by Twilio
const stringPayload = querystring.stringify(payload);

// Configure the request details
var requestDetails = {
  hostname: "api.twilio.com",
  method: "POST",
  path: `/2010-04-01/Accounts/${config.twilio.accountSid}/Messages.json`,
  auth: `${config.twilio.accountSid}:${config.twilio.authToken}`,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
  }
};

// Instantiate the request
const req = https.request(requestDetails, res => {
  // grab the status of the sent request
  const status = res.statusCode;
  console.log([
    `(sendTwilioSms) making https post request`,
    `(sendTwilioSms) response completed: ${res.complete}`,
    `(sendTwilioSms) response statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`,
    { "(sendTwilioSms) response headers:": res.headers },
    { "(sendTwilioSms) response body:": res.body }
  ]);
  // callback successfully if the request went through
  if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
    callback(false);
  } else {
    callback(500, {
      Error: `Status code returned was ${status}: ${res.statusMessage}`
    });
  }
});

    // Alert the user as to a change in their check status
workers.alertUserToStatusChange = newCheckData => {
  const message = `Alert: Your check for ${newCheckData.method.toUpperCase()} ${
    newCheckData.protocol
  }://${newCheckData.url} is currently ${newCheckData.state}`;
  helpers.sendTwilioSms(newCheckData.userPhone, message, err => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(
        "Success: User was aterted to a status change in their check, via sms: ",
        msg
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Error: Could not send sms alert to user who add a state change in their check"
      );
    }
  });
```

Here's the Response:

```
    [
  '(workers) making check request',
  '(workers) check response completed: false',
  '(workers) check response statusCode: 200'
]
logging to file succeeded
Check outcome has not changed no alert needed
[
  '(sendTwilioSms) making https post request',
  '(sendTwilioSms) response completed: false',
  '(sendTwilioSms) response statusCode: 400',
  {
    '(sendTwilioSms) response headers:': {
      date: 'Fri, 17 Jan 2020 09:49:39 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '127',
      connection: 'close',
      'twilio-request-id': 'RQ7ee0b52d100c4ac997222f235e760fb7',
      'twilio-request-duration': '0.025',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, '
+
        'If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, ' +
        'If-Unmodified-Since',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'x-powered-by': 'AT-5000',
      'x-shenanigans': 'none',
      'x-home-region': 'us1',
      'x-api-domain': 'api.twilio.com',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000'
    }
  },
  { '(sendTwilioSms) response body:': undefined }
]
Error: Could not send sms alert to user who add a state change in their check
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
// authentication
var authenticationHeader = "Basic "
    + new Buffer(config.twilio.accountSid
        + ":"
        + config.twilio.authToken).toString("base64");

// Configure the request details
var requestDetails = {
    host: "api.twilio.com",
    port: 443,
    method: "POST",
    path: `/2010-04-01/Accounts/${config.twilio.accountSid}/Messages.json`,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload),
        "Authorization": authenticationHeader
    }
};
```

and this:

```
// Instantiate the request
const req = https.request(requestDetails, res => {
    // grab the status of the sent request
    const status = res.statusCode;

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
        // If we know it's JSON, parse it
        if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        }
        callback(null, body);
    });

    // callback successfully if the request went through
    if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(500, {
            Error: `Status code returned was ${status}: ${res.statusMessage}`
        });
    }
});
```

---

I hope it works, I have not tested. If it doesn't let me know and I'll try on my side and post a complete tested code.

Comment: Thanks alot. I was able to use this to debug my code. Turns out the payload keys were case sensitive.